# Как установить общее событие на изменения значения любого элемента формы?

Tags: javascript, html, события, html-form

Есть формочка с различными элементами ввода. Нужно при изменении значений в любом элементе отлавливать только факт изменения значений внутри этой формы. Как это можно сделать простым способом, что бы не вешать кучу обработчиков на каждый элемент?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так:

```js
function handler(event) {
  console.log(event.type, event.target)
}

var form = document.querySelector('form')

form.addEventListener('input', handler)
form.addEventListener('change', handler)
```

```html
<form>
  <input type=text>
  <input type=checkbox>
  <input type=radio name=a>
  <input type=radio name=a>
  <input type=radio name=a>
  <select><option>1<option>4<option>3</select>
  <textarea></textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: спасибо то что нужно